# Esconder checkbox e exibir outro

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiz uma pequena validação em meu script só que não estou conseguindo fazer a seguinte validação.

Eu tenho 2 checkbox, cada um execulta uma ação, como podem ver no meu `if` abaixo.

```
@if (item.Cadeado == 1 && item.cadeadoAH == 1) {
  <input type="checkbox" name="check_LiberarFormulario" data-form="AltaUti" data-value="@item.PatientId" data-content="@item.PatientId" checked style="height: 14px;">
} else {
  <input type="checkbox" name="check_BloquearFormulario" data-form="AltaUtiDesc" data-value="@item.PatientId" data-content="@item.PatientId" style="height: 14px;">
}
```

Abaixo esta os dois scripts destes dois checkbox

```
   $('[name="check_LiberarFormulario"]').click(function (element) {
        var $btn = $('#' + element.id);
        var id = $(this).attr('data-value');
        var formulario = $(this).attr('data-form');

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Formulario/Cadastro/AbrirCadeadoForm',
            data: { 'id': id, 'formulario': formulario },
            success: function (response) {
                notif({
                    'type': 'danger',
                    'msg': '<b>Formulário Liberado!</b> Sua página será atualizada em alguns segundos',
                    'position': 'center',
                    'multiline': true,
                    'timeout': 2000
                })
            },
            error: function (response) {
                $('.resultadoSalvar.modal').modal('show');
                $('#tituloSalvo45').text('Ocorreu um erro');
                $('#mensagemResultadoSalvar').text('Ocorreu um erro inesperado, entre em contato com o suporte!');
            }
        });
    });

    $('[name="check_BloquearFormulario"]').click(function (element) {
        var $btn = $('#' + element.id);
        var id = $(this).attr('data-value');
        var formulario = $(this).attr('data-form');

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Formulario/Cadastro/AbrirCadeadoForm',
            data: { 'id': id, 'formulario': formulario },
            success: function (response) {
                notif({
                    'type': 'success',
                    'msg': '<b>Formulário Bloqueado!</b>',
                    'position': 'center',
                    'autohide': true,
                    'multiline': true,
                    'timeout': 2000
                })
            },
            error: function (response) {
                $('.resultadoSalvar.modal').modal('show');
                $('#tituloSalvo45').text('Ocorreu um erro');
                $('#mensagemResultadoSalvar').text('Ocorreu um erro inesperado, entre em contato com o suporte!');
            }
        });
    });
```

Quando o **check_LiberarFormulario** for removido o check o **check_BloquearFormulario** deve ser exibido, vice e versa, ou seja, clicar em um e exibir o outro, sendo que na hora de carregar a pagina só pode aparecer uma opção.

Eu tentei fazer com show() e hide() fadeIn() e FadeOut() só que não obtive sucesso em nenhuma destas opções.

Answer (score 1):

Já tentou utilizar o método **toggle** do jQuery?
[Veja mais aqui](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```js
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( "p" ).toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Toggle</button>
<p>Hello</p>
<p style="display: none">Good Bye</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer usando jquery:

```
var check1 = $("#id-do-check-1");
var check2 = $("#id-do-check-2");

check1.on("change", function () {
        if (check1.find("input:checked").length) {
            check2.show();
        }
        else {
            check2.hide();
        }
    }
);
```

Veja o exemplo completo: https://jsfiddle.net/0k807jjt/10/